# Evaluate $\int_{\pi}^{3 \pi/2}\frac{1}{1-\rho \sin{2 \theta }} d\theta$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I would like to evaluate

> $$\int_{\pi}^{3 \pi/2}\frac{1}{1-\rho \sin{2 \theta }} d\theta$$

For $-1<\rho <1$. Unfortunately nothing I have tried has got me very far so I would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a [general trick for integrating rational functions of trigonometric functions by substituting $t=\tan(x/2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Comment: @YourAdHere Wow, didn't  know about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice, $$\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\frac{1}{1-\rho \sin2\theta}\ d\theta$$
$$=\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\frac{1}{1-\rho \frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}}\ d\theta$$
$$=\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta-2\rho \tan\theta}\ d\theta$$
$$=\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{(\tan\theta-\rho)^2+1-\rho^2}\ d\theta$$
$$=\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\frac{d(\tan\theta-\rho)}{(\tan\theta-\rho)^2+(\sqrt{1-\rho^2})^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\theta-\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)\right]_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\infty\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)\right]$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\left(\frac \pi 2+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)\right)}$$